# Is it actually known that the Mordell curve has such a large solution?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

Here :

[Examples of Diophantine equations with a large finite number of solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387950/examples-of-diophantine-equations-with-a-large-finite-number-of-solutions)

if I understood it right, in one of the answers it is claimed that the Mordell-equation

$$y^2=x^3+154319269$$ has a solution with $x>10^{10^{13}}$

> Is it actually KNOWN that a solution with that magnitude must exist, or did I misunderstand the answer ?